# Download an image using Axios and convert it to base64

Tags: javascript, axios

I need to download a .jpg image from a remote server and convert it into a base64 format. I'm using axios as my HTTP client. I've tried issuing a git request to the server and checking the `response.data` however it doesn't seem to work like that.

Link to axios: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios

Link to base64 implementation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64

I'm using NodeJS / React so atob/btoa doesn't work, hense the library.

```
axios.get('http://placehold.it/32').then(response => {
    console.log(response.data); // Blank
    console.log(response.data == null); // False 
    console.log(base64.encode(response.data); // Blank
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Have you tried to change responseType to say blob? From docs "// `responseType` indicates the type of data that the server will respond with"

Answer (score 363):

This worked great for me:

```js
function getBase64(url) {
  return axios
    .get(url, {
      responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    })
    .then(response => Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64'))
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly well! I would upvote 100 times if I could!

Comment: if you're using `react-native`, add this to the top of your files: `global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer`

Comment: Thank you, works great! If you're putting the base64 in <img src="" ... then don't forget to prefix the base64 string with "data:image/jpeg;base64, "

Comment: **DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from()
methods instead.**

Comment: that should be Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary'))

Comment: can you imagine I spent about 5+ hours trying to find out why the file wasn't loading correctly

Comment: Where can I find documentation about Buffer.from?

Comment: This can break on requests, that return something other than image (e.g. HTML page with successful status code, e.g. from redirect). A check wheather the buffer is an actual image, would be needed.

Comment: for you working with react-script v5, you must install buffer dependency first. and import it. 
```npm install buffer```

Comment: A Big Thanks to the questioner and answerer! A little thing but it saved a lot of hours of efforts. The answer should be marked as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 38):

There might be a better way to do this, but I have done it like this (minus the extra bits like `catch()`, etc.):

```
axios.get(imageUrl, { responseType:"blob" })
    .then(function (response) {

        var reader = new window.FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(response.data); 
        reader.onload = function() {

            var imageDataUrl = reader.result;
            imageElement.setAttribute("src", imageDataUrl);

        }
    });
```

I have a suspicion that at least part of your problem might be server-side.  Even without setting `{ responseType: "blob" }` you should have had something in your `response.data` output.

Comment: after searching for hours I found the solution. Thank you!!

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Something for others to pay attention to is needing to attach an event listener to `load`. This is essential for getting the result after reading the data into the FileReader isntance.

Answer (score 28):

This is what works for me (with `Buffer.from`) -

```
axios
  .get(externalUrl, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  })
  .then(response => {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data, 'base64');
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.error(ex);
  });
```

Comment: `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` was what needed in my case!

Comment: `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` and `Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary')` for download the `pdf` file.

Answer (score 7):

using `responseType: "text", responseEncoding: "base64"` will get response body encoded as base64 string

for example, the sample code will get base64 and write a jpg file to disk.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import fs from "fs";

axios
  .get("https://picsum.photos/255", {
    responseType: "text",
    responseEncoding: "base64",
  })
  .then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp.data);
    fs.writeFileSync("./test.jpg", resp.data, { encoding: "base64" });
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the blob to base64 from [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) api and then display it.

```
 const fileReaderInstance = new FileReader();
 fileReaderInstance.readAsDataURL(blob); 
 fileReaderInstance.onload = () => {
 base64data = fileReaderInstance.result;                
 console.log(base64data);
 }
```

and display it as:

```
   <Image source={{uri: base64ImageData}} />
```

Comment: OP requested `axios`, otherwise that's a great solution for the browser!

Answer (score 2):

```
import { Axios } from "axios";

const axios = new Axios({});

const res = await axios.get(url, {
  responseType: "text",
  responseEncoding: "base64",
});

const base64 = Buffer.from(res.data, "base64");
```