# Download an image using axios post request

Tags: javascript, highcharts, axios

I need base64 image chart from 'http://export.highcharts.com/'

```
    getImg () {
          const self = this;
          axios.post('http://export.highcharts.com/', { options: self.$refs['lineChart'].options, type: 'image/png' }).then(function (response) {
            base64.encode(response.data)
          }).catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e)
          });
    },
```

Comment: Why `post` and not `get`? https://codepen.io/dotexe0/pen/qBBwxvG

Comment: you have to use `get` not `post`

Comment: Highcharts api provides get method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine

```
getImg () {
          const self = this;
          axios.post('http://export.highcharts.com/', { options: self.$refs['lineChart'].options, type: 'image/png' }, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(function (response) {
            let PNGBase64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' + Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64')
          }).catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e)
          });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get image and convert it to base64. also similar to this question you can check the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846669/download-an-image-using-axios-and-convert-it-to-base64) to get more information.

```js
function getBase64(url) {
      return axios
        .get(url, {
          responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        })
        .then(response => Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64'))
    }
```