# ReactJS Axios Image Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

[image]I want make a request to API with headers having UserID:Pass

Example :

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    'X-RPC-DIRECTORY': 'main',
    'X-RPC-AUTHORIZATION': 'userid:pass'
  }
};

const res = await axios.get(`http://192.00.00.60:8000/obj/e1b8c19e-fe8c-43af-800c-c9400c0e90/abc.jpg`, config );
```

How can I render this?
Using the same I can get the image in Postman, But I want to render this into the page.

Comment: http://192.00.00.60:8000/obj/e1b8c19e-fe8c-43af-800c-c9400c0e90/abc.jpg what you are trying to do here

Comment: you have api / want to access your image url ???

Comment: I want to render this jpg, but when I use this link directly, its showing this : {"message":"Couldn't create client credentials","errorReason":"MissingCredentials","error":"MissingCredentialException","path":"/obj/e1b8c19e-fe8c-43af-800c-30c9400c0e90/cutout.jpg","verb":"GET","status":401,"timestamp":1580278417361}

Comment: It might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846669/download-an-image-using-axios-and-convert-it-to-base64

Comment: @PrakashKarena exactly, I have API and Image URL, I just want to access that image url from API, but it need authorization to access  problem is that I don't know how.

Comment: what is role of your api from backend ? what you are doing when you are passing your image url to your api ??

Comment: if you have problem with authentication then make sure you have your headers in backend side with your request

Answer (score 4):

1- Create *useState* to save your **base64** data.

```
const [base64, setBase64] = useState();
```

2- Create *useEffect* or *function* to transform image from get request to **base64**.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        url,
        {
          responseType: "arraybuffer",
        }
      )
      .then((response) =>
        setBase64(Buffer.from(response.data, "binary").toString("base64"))
      );
  }, []);
```

3- Display the **base64** data as image according to the syntax of the [data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Syntax):

```
<img src={data:[<media type>][;charset=<character set>][;base64],<data>} />
```

example:

```
<img src={`data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,${base64}`} />
```

Comment: This is quite helpful for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
axios({
        method:'get',
        url,
        auth: {
            username: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {

        //From here you can pass the response to local variable(state) and store/show image. 

       this.setState({ imageURL : response.data.image }); // change this as per your response 

    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });

render(){
return(
  <React.Fragment>
   <img src={this.state.imageURL} alt="image" />
  </React.Fragment>
)
}
```

Make sure you have right method type, URL and data is coming in response.

Comment: the response I'm getting is not image url, instead its data, so, when I save that data as .jpg from postman, then its the image what i want, My question is that : How can I render that (data / response ) as image, because its not image url its data. (I've add the screenshot)

Comment: If the data is of base64, you can try this way. 
<img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${this.state.image}`} />

Comment: this is what i'm getting : -                                                                             GET data:image/jpeg;base64,{props.getImage.firstImage} net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Comment: Why are you rendering through props? 
You have response coming from an API, you store that response in one local component's state and render through the same state.

Comment: its because i'm using redux for state, props.getImage.firstImage contains : { data, status, statusText, headers, config, request}

Answer (score 0):

```
class Hello extends Component {
  state = {
    ulr: ''
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      const config = {
      headers: {
      'X-RPC-DIRECTORY': 'main',
      'X-RPC-AUTHORIZATION': 'userid:pass'
      }
    };

  axios.get(`http://192.00.00.60:8000/obj/e1b8c19e-fe8c-43af-800c-c9400c0e90/abc.jpg`, config ).then((response) => {
    this.setState({ url: response.data })
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <img src={this.state.url} alt="#" />
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default Hello;
```

This should answer how to render the image after fetching the image from API.
But what i think is something is wrong withe URL.
i have few question:

1. Is the back-end API hosted on our own system?
2. Is the API publicly available because if it's not we cannot access it.
3. Have you set ant other headers or params that needs to be sent along the request.
4. I tried with postman also didn't get the image in response, it gave me error.

Comment: Yes Back-end API hosted on local system, to access it we need header  -> { 'X-RPC-AUTHORIZATION': 'userid:pass' }  -  but the problem is that the response is data not the image url,  so that means when I save that data ( response ) as .jpg file from postman, then its working, So, my questions is that : How can I render that (data / response ) as image.

Comment: @SRTechConnect since i cant access the API as it's not publicly available can you past the response here thate you are getting. I am bit confused do you expect a resource URL to that image in API response or the content byte of the image?

Comment: I think you might be receiving the content-byte data of image let me see the response then i can suggest a possible solution.

Comment: @PrasanKumar - Please check added the screen shot of response

Comment: @SRTechConnect the problem is not on the react side. what i am seeing is you haven't stored the image in DB the right way. what i would suggest is not store images in DB at all. store them somewhere in a file system and store there relative path to the DB. in this way your DB remains light weight and you can send a resource URL of the image in the API response. and place that resource URL in the <img src="URL" />. depending upon what stack you have used on back-end there are many article that could help you with this to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Got the Solution, as the response was content-type: blob so, what I did is to convert the blob to base64 from FileReader api and then display it.

```
const fileReaderInstance = new FileReader();
 fileReaderInstance.readAsDataURL(blob); 
 fileReaderInstance.onload = () => {
     base64data = fileReaderInstance.result;                
     console.log(base64data);
 }
```