# get image through axios how to display on my react project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, getimagedata

i have a image object that is getting through axios and how to retrive my image from this object and how to display it in my react project. i am using this object in "" tag but its not working...

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

function MyUploader() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");

  const getimage = () => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:4000/getAllPosts").then((res) => {
      let result = (res && res.data && res.data[0].file) || [];
      setImage(result[0]);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img src={image} alt=""/>
      <button onClick={getImage}>getdata</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

there is my data object in which availabel of images array as the name of "files" that i am getting from axios request. and my question is this that how to display images in my project...

```js
{
category: "women"
colors: (3) ['yellow', 'gray', 'green']
createdAt: "2021-10-03T18:13:02.711Z"
description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of"
discount: 10
file: Array(3)
0: {fieldname: 'file', originalname: 'WhatsApp Image 2021-09-08 at 11.54.30 AM.jpeg', encoding: '7bit', mimetype: 'image/jpeg', destination: './public/newPostData/', …}
1: {fieldname: 'file', originalname: 'WhatsApp Image 2021-09-07 at 10.50.05 PM.jpeg', encoding: '7bit', mimetype: 'image/jpeg', destination: './public/newPostData/', …}
2: {fieldname: 'file', originalname: 'WhatsApp Image 2021-09-07 at 12.25.49 PM.jpeg', encoding: '7bit', mimetype: 'image/jpeg', destination: './public/newPostData/', …}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
id: 1
name: "Flare Dress"
new: true
pictures: (4) ['/assets/images/fashion/product/1.jpg', '/assets/images/fashion/product/21.jpg', '/assets/images/fashion/product/36.jpg', '/assets/images/fashion/product/12.jpg']
price: 12000
rating: 4
sale: true
salePrice: 20000
shortDetails: "Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natu"
size: (3) ['M', 'L', 'XL']
stock: 16
tags: (2) ['nike', 'caprese']
updatedAt: "2021-10-03T18:13:02.711Z"
variants: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
__v: 0
_id: "6159f2ae77433b2df4e1ee43"
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59961315/reactjs-axios-image-request
Use this approach.

Comment: i can't better solution from this link plese explane it here in the answor box...

Answer (score 2):

Change your `getImage` method to this:

```
const getImage = () => {
  Axios.get("http://localhost:4000/getAllPosts", {
      responseType: "arraybuffer"
    })
    .then((res) => {
    const base64 = btoa(
      new Uint8Array(res.data).reduce(
        (data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte),
        ''
      )
    )
    setImage(base64)
  })
}
```

Usage:

```
<img src={`data:;base64,${image}`} />

// or

<img src={`data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,${image}`} />
```

Comment: i have no just file data in "axios response", in this response getting a data object that contain different variables, arrays and here is one array of images objects. in this method my data object is converting into "arraybuffer". i want convert just images array into "bufferArray". plese tell me how do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a good practice to mess up binary data with metadata. Better to have an endpoint that would return binary and right headers for browser to display it like that:

```
<img src="https://yourapi.com/image/2"/>
```

Comment: Sometimes you want to add header for auth etc.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your try block after the request:

```
if (res) {
                const base64 = btoa(
                    new Uint8Array(res.data).reduce(
                        (data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte),
                        ''
                    )
                )
                setImage(`data:;base64,${base64}`)
            }
```