# request to static image file returned weird data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

im doing this request:

```html
const res = await axios.get(`/images/57fe41e5-2205-4a0a-b276-4b95d7f78985.png`);
```

and i get this data:
[image]
is someone know how to handle this?

Comment: Why are you using http call to get something which is local to your project? axios is for rest calls . you can simply import the file and use it

Comment: Those are the bytes of the image, but you are trying to visualise them as utf8 character, thus why you get those boxes. You would get the same result when trying to open an image in notepad++.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi the file sits on the server

Comment: Okay , then I think Nicolas has answered your question

Comment: @Nicolas is there a way to convert it back to buffer or something like that?

Comment: @gdsdasgga , check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846669/download-an-image-using-axios-and-convert-it-to-base64

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download an image using Axios and convert it to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846669/download-an-image-using-axios-and-convert-it-to-base64)

Comment: Good to hear that . Happy learning!