# Can we print a path-defined pdf using reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, printing, printjs

I want to print a pdf file which is obtained from GET request from
*router.js*

```
router.get('/fetch-pdf',(req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/result.pdf`)
})
```

and my react component is like

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
const App = () => {
  handleClick() {
    axios.get('/fetch-pdf').then((res) => {
      // someway to print
    })
  }
  return(
    <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>Click</button>
  )
}
export default APp
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your would be using print.js based on the question tag. The library accepts base64 data, therefore, you can just pass that into the `printJS` function.

Here is one way to get base64 from the axios response data and pass into the lib:

```js
axios.get('/fetch-pdf', {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).then(res => {
  const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data, 'base64');

  printJS({printable: buffer, type: 'pdf', base64: true})
})
```

Axios response to base64 [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846669/download-an-image-using-axios-and-convert-it-to-base64).

The print.js library does the same when caching pdf files, however it does that without axios. You can see the lib code here if interested:
https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/blob/master/src/js/pdf.js