# Fetch and display image in React JS

Tags: reactjs, image, png, encode, display

I have a code block like this. I am getting data with this Function.

cloudApi.jsx file:

```
export const fileApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: cloud_url, 
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    CLIENTID: clientID,
    CLIENTACCESSKEY: clientAccessKey,
    CLIENTSECRETKEY: clientsecretKey,
  },
  credentials: 'include'
});

export const FileService = {
  async getFile(path) {
    try {
      const response = await fileApi.get(path); 
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
    }
  },
};
```

And this is Logo.jsx file:

```
  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState("");

  const getFile = async () => {
    try {
      const path = "src/assets/icons/googleIcon.png";
      const response = await FileService.getFile(path);
      console.log("response", response);      
      setImageSrc(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getFile();
  }, []);
```

and Response give me a data below;

Result:

�PNG

IHDR00W��   pHYs���IDATx��oLeǟ{Zz�-F��a�?����2
��ű��4�f�c��
�1(�A `q&6덻:\�ڍ�"�7�C��N�sm�UH��٣eI���]����]��O���?($���b(�,�{�M�   J� @*HC6�&A���:T�� _4R����6a�$��$,�ƷA�}�:Y8��,�)�YS@1���x � ��c�=��p�Э�y�������=< ��ߍ�~���I���h~��8����N4x���=x,2��D�ୱOB%��&i PhP(�HނӘr�6��8[�M��7�!�AXy�����Y|@�g���*�R��oT����/��p�(x�y�������`�|   @��<z$A-`&u`&����t���ߐ�z$�l~Y��Q�
��IX���6b�$�_�T��I�9������0ɴN�:���6j�L^q)`�u�/X3b4\;a;��w׽���s)������u��<t#�+��5��|�@�}%��z�j��U߂����0_ ��޴=݋��Q��L���F;}%pD7<�C@v�I��g�����^�DN�p��菾��(��8�^�T8����CW���{Il��������{@̲{K�63   �X8d;��ͣ����_�&|[�zgd��� ��Z���(~O��D6��7m��L�2��V�&/p\�Ǐ)��i�l���/ik��=)p�/��:�)�R?ff<��8J���3�v�������XA�70�W�+�D���[���ވ�^�U����Xs���=�J>���ȧ��ί�P�)rw��Emjg����֜�8����J}zJЗ�r�٘�,+EX�t�q/�g#\�t��2`�J�h�SW�$L�_�rL�H�P���;��7u#O�c��
xҢ�r�Y}g��M?"O��G�4t�}oH~Q��&|z������tp|b8n�s5L�7$��sA�za��~���,?+dM���c�Fc�����3F5�2��_yC����iF��0�'����zǐ�1x��Î�~�ƫ���34���Ud8�X(x��������|k�$�g�[��F�L��j:mQePZ�w�~�5d�Ԇ�Ūk��-�~��S`�����i��%g '`]IEND�B`�

I want to display this response image data in img object but I don't know how I can do that.

```
 <img className="logo" src={mainLogo} alt="PNG Image" />
```

I try this code but it didn't work.

```
  const getFile = async () => {
    try {
      const path = "src/assets/icons/googleIcon.png";
      const response = await FileService.getFile(path);
      setImageSrc(`data:image/png;base64, ${response}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Take a look at this CodeSandbox example. There is no need to fetch the image you can directly insert the path into the src prop of <img>

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ways-to-import-images-5d7fe?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js

Comment: I am fetching data because I am taking data from cloud.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are getting a blob you need, need to set response type and process it accordinly

```
 const getFile = async () => {
    try {
      const path = "src/assets/icons/googleIcon.png";
      const response = await FileService.getFile(path, { responseType:"blob" });
var reader = new window.FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(response); 
        reader.onload = function() {

            var imageDataUrl = reader.result;
setImageSrc(imageDataUrl);

        }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: you can also use response type of buffer any one that works for you you can also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846669/download-an-image-using-axios-and-convert-it-to-base64