# Discord Image conversion (Base 64)

Tags: node.js, axios, discord, discord.js, google-gemini

I am trying to convert my discord image into Base 64 from a link so it can be used in Googles [Gemini Pro Vision Model](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/node_quickstart#generate-text-from-text-and-image-input). However I am encountering an error every time. I believe it occurs when the axios function is run, but I am not 100% sure.

##### Code:

```js
                async function run(message) {

                    const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-pro-vision" });
                    console.log("Pass 1")
                    
                    const imageAttachmentUrls = message.attachments
                      .filter(attachIsImage) 
                      .map((attachment) => attachment.url)
                      .filter((url) => !!url);
                  
                    console.log("Pass 2")
                    if (imageAttachmentUrls.length === 0) {
                      console.log("No valid image attachments found in the message.");
                      return; 
                    }

                    console.log("Pass 3")
                    function getBase64(url) {
                        console.log("Pass 5")
                        return axios
                          .get(url, {
                            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
                          })
                          .then(response => Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64'))
                    }

                    console.log("Pass 4")

                    console.log(imageAttachmentUrls[0]);

                    const image = {
                        inlineData: {
                          data: await getBase64(imageAttachmentUrls[0]),
                          mimeType: "image/png",
                        },
                      };

                    console.log("Pass 6")
                    
                    const prompt = "What's this picture?";
                    const result = await model.generateContent([prompt, image]); 
                    console.log(result);
                  }

                  run(message);
            }
```

#### Console:

```
Pass 1
Pass 2
Pass 3
Pass 4
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1213885940909744139/1216332602538065940/image.png?ex=66000102&is=65ed8c02&hm=a3901233e34d1b1239928d97dfbe882553212cde5d841560d252be3d768acc8b&
Pass 5
Pass 6
 Critical Error detected:

 {} unhandledRejection
```

**Additional Notes:**

I have been trying different ways to convert the URL to Base 64 and in the end, I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44058739/20077293), although it still did not work.

- Expected the Model to return a result and log it in the console successfully.